# Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` with `id="modal"` generated dynamically with the jQuery `load()` method:

```
$('#modal').load('handlers/word.edit.php');
```

`word.edit.php` contains a few input element, which are loaded into a modal `<div>`.

Using jQuery's `keyup` method I can capture the input values after an event fires, but
when the elements are added dynamically to the modal div, the event no llonger fires when the user enters their text.

Which jQuery method supports handling events triggered by dynamically created elements?

The code for creating the new input elements is:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('<input id="'+i+'" type="text" name="translations' + i + '"  />')
      .appendTo('#modal');
```

The code for capturing the user's values is:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    handler = $(this).val();
    name = $(this).attr('name');
```

This second code block seems to work for the original elements, but it is not fired by the new dynamically generated elements.

Comment: I also loaded the two versions of jQuery on my **index.php**    `<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.min.js"></script>`

but work not the function **on** only work the function **live**
**edit: #modal to input**

  `$('input').live('keyup', 'input', function() {
   handler = $(this).val();
   name = $(this).attr('name');
   alert(handler+" "+name);
  });`
when I using code so it work fine, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Just a note. You dont load two versions of JQuery. You load a version 1.6.2 of JQuery and 1.8.18 of JQuery UI. JQuery UI is used for user interface components and is not the same thing of JQuery. For best pratice try to use JQuery from online resource like Google instead of local file.

Comment: @Carlos Eduardo Bruno Pereira
Thanks for the good clearing,
I always believed that both have the same package already exist
only the -ui with extra features added but it wasn't so :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to [delegate the event](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events) to the closest static ancestor element within the page (see also ["Understanding Event Delegation"](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)). This simply means, the element where you bind your event handler must *already exist* at the time the handler is bound, so for dynamically generated elements you must allow the event to bubble up and handle it further up.

The jQuery [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method is the way to do this (or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) for older versions of jQuery.)

```
// If version 1.7 or above

$('#modal').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    handler = $(this).val();
    name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Or in older versions

```
// If version 1.6 or below

// note the selector and event are in a different order than above
$('#modal').delegate('input', 'keyup', function()
{
    handler = $(this).val();
    name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Comment: Your answer, the article you linked to, and @ernie mentioning the `<parentSelector>` all really helped me understand how `.on()` works. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This is happening because you're adding the input element *after* you wired up the event.  Try [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    handler = $(this).val();
    name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Using `.on` will make sure the `keyup` event is wired up to inputs that are on the page originally, as well as any that are added later dynamically.

Comment: I am sorry, 
before was working inputs which loaded before appendTo() in the **modal** div
but now both arent't work and I didn't understand what the different is **on**
using and I think inputs element founds in **modal** div not in **body** 
but each div must founds in **body** I don't know but it isn't work

Comment: You can change `'body'` to any selector you feel like.  That selector should work, though.  Your modal HTML will still be inside the body, as it can't be outside it.

Answer (score 3):

When you dynamically change the DOM, jQuery won't attach event handlers to them.  You need to use [on() and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

For your input items, you'll need something like:

```
$("<parentSelector>").on("keyup", "input", function() { 
    handler = $(this).val();
    name = $(this).attr('name');
})
```

Where the parentSelector is something higher in the DOM than the input element, and an element that exists at page load, maybe the form ID or something.

Comment: Your last sentence really helped me understand this concept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Function binds are made ​​in page load. To work on elements created dynamically using the function live (). Example:

```
$ ("p"). live ("click", function () {
    // Your function
});
```

Comment: Just as a note, [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, so it's a good idea to switch to [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture changes for all of the form elements, particularly select boxes, I know they are not mentioned here, but it is helpful to know, use the following code:

```
$(document).on('change', ':input', function () {
   alert('value of ' + $(this).attr('name') + ' changed')
});
```

This should cover all `input`, `textarea`, `select`, `checkbox`, `radio`, etc.