# .click not fired for <p> tag within jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with the .click function working for a

tag within a jQuery dialog.

I have a a p tag that looks like below, inside a jQuery dialog.

```
<p class="userColor" id="CMP|8|25691/XX|25691/59|59" style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;">59   - GRAPE</p>
```

div

```
<div id="colorPickerWindow" style="width: auto; min-height: 89px; max-height: none; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <p class="userColor" id="CMP|8|25691/XX|25691/20|20" style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;">20   - RED</p>
</div>
```

I have tried .click and .on and I have tried both using a selector, but I cannot get the a click action to fire for the P tag.

jQuery

```
$(".userColor").on({
    click:function(){}            
});
```

What is the correct jQuery to get a click event to fire within a jQuery dialog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work :

```
$(document).on("click", ".userColor", function(){
 alert("yippie");
});
```

Or (click alone will not work if content is dynamically loaded)

```
$(".userColor").click(function(){
 alert("yippie");
});
```

Comment: .click doesn't work because I am dynamically loading the div with content.

Comment: Ok you didn't specify that information so first one should work? does it?

Comment: Yes you still need to use document.

Comment: Though it's one of possible approaches, in general there is no need to use document for this at all - as the content is loaded dynamically it's just required to attach the listener at the right time - once the element loading is finished. This particular point in time depends on the method one uses to add an element, but jquery provides callbacks for that - just place "click attaching logic" under that callback and you should be good

Answer (score 1):

If your content is loaded dynamically, use this format of `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".userColor", function(event){
   //dostuff
});
```

From the [.on() docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Comment: I am already within the $(document).ready(function(){} realm, do I still use the $(document) ?

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell: One has nothing to do with the other. Read the documentation about delegated event handlers.

Comment: Yes, the `(document).ready(` code just executes your jQuery once the DOM is ready. If you're dynamically loading elements into your page, as you say you are, then you need to bind event to them using .on() in the way I showed.