# jquery event not working after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/YsnhT/2/

Jquery event on is not working after the append. I need the value of textarea after I click save button.

```
$('.span8')
    .on('click',
            '.btn',
            function() {
        var input = $("#textarea").val();
        alert(input);
    });

$('body').on('click','#createNote',function() {                $('.span8').empty();
                $('.span8').append('<button type="button" class="btn" style="float: right; margin-right: 8px;background-color:#dddddd;font-family:Roboto Slab;color: black" id="save" data-loading-text="Saving...">Save</button><div class="hero-unit"><input type="text" style="width: 100%" id="title" placeholder="Title"/>'+ 
                '<textarea contenteditable="true" id="textarea" class="textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..."style="width: 100%;">dd</textarea></div>');

            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="span8"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `#save` is dynamically created, use the following handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#save' ,function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/YsnhT/3/

You should also make your "click" button handler like this, or else it will not fire on newly created `#click` buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Simply delegate the event in dynamic format:

```
$(document).on('click', '#save' ,function() {
    //do stuff
})
```

And perhaps do the same for:

```
$(document).on('click', '#click' ,function() {
    //do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

save is creating dynamically here.So try to using `on`

```
$(document).on('click', '#save' ,function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have appended the element you need to rebind the handlers to it or use jQuery's live() function, like so:

```
$('.span8 .btn').live('click', function() {
    var input = $("#textarea").val();
    alert(input);
});
```

Comment: `live` seems to be deprecated. you must go with `on` instead. like the other posts suggests.

Answer (score 0):

check this...

$('.btn').click(function() {

```
 var input = $("#textarea").val();
    alert(input);
```

});