# .click() function being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm generating list items that go in an unordered list. I then want to listen for a click on any of these list items. I'm aware I haven't posted the full code, but I'm hoping it isn't necessary for me to. Are elements that are appended like this completely ignored by my jQuery click function? I've tried just about everything and can't find out why! All I want to see is my "lol" alert! :(

```
  $.each(entries, function(i, v) {
    s += '<li';
    if (favouriteItem(v.title)) s += ' data-theme="e"';
    s += '><a href="#feedItemPage" class="contentLink" data-transition="slide" data-entryid="'+i+'">' + v.title + '</a></li>';
  });

  $("#linksList").append(s);
  $("#linksList").listview("refresh");

    $("li").click(function() {
      alert("lol");
      selectedEntry = $(this).data("entryid");
    });
```

Although the items do visually appear the source code stays like this:

```
  <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="linksList" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="false"></ul>
  </div>
```

Suggesting that there are no li elements there. Yet they do show visually? Someone please save me before I jump into a pool of lava.

Comment: "the source code stays like this". How are you checking that? Are you using the developer tools or just "view source"ing?

Comment: The reason you're not seeing them in source code will be an artifact of the way that you're viewing the source. If you rightclick->view source then chances are it will show you the source as it was when the browser received it.

Try using the developer tools. I can't remember exactly how to get to them in all browsers, but in firefox it's tools->developer tools

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't aware it wouldn't show in the view source page in Chrome. That's how I was checking it, I'll use developer tools next time. 8-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
$("li").click(function() {
  alert("lol");
  selectedEntry = $(this).data("entryid");
});
```

to

```
$('#linksList').on('click', 'li',function() {
  alert("lol");
  selectedEntry = $(this).data("entryid");
});
```

When you add elements dynamically to the document, you need to use [`.on()'s`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated event syntax.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Comment: Brings confusion because the behavior changes based on how you call the method

Comment: @abdulwakeel - it's only confusing if you don't read the documentation.

Comment: .bind(), .live(), and .delegate() is all combined in on

Comment: @abdulwakeel Just for the record in case others view this, .live() was deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. That one bugged me for ages before finally checking.

Comment: the .on() method as being "overloaded" with different signatures, so maybe the question poster using old version than jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation:

```
$("#linksList").on('click',"li",function() {
      alert("lol");
      selectedEntry = $(this).data("entryid");
    });
```