# jQuery click event not passed to appended span

Tags: jquery

I click on div with `id="tube_clx"`.

This action appends to div with `id="tube"` a span with `id="trash"`.

When I click on span with id="trash".   I expect alert to pop, yet it does not.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
<div>
    <div id="tube_clx">[click div]</div>
    <div id="tube"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 

        $('#tube_clx').on('click', function(){ 
            $('#tube').append('<span id="trash">[click span]</span>');
        });

        $('#trash').on('click', function(){ 
            alert('hi');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: you are right @Felix Kling (dupe), but my demo code and (especially) adeneo fiddle and explanation makes this "bubbly problem" much better explained; having said that, if I came across answer mentioned by you  (not that I did not look for it), this question would not be here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler is bound to any element with an ID of `#trash`, but as you haven't clicked `#tube_clx` yet, there is no such element in the DOM.
To attach the event to any future elements with the ID `#trash`, you have to use a delegated event handler, like so :

```
$('#tube').on('click', '#trash', function(){ 
    alert('hi');
});
```

Also note that it's not `$('.tube_clx')`, but `$('#tube_clx')`, as it's the elements ID.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WPRBN/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#trash')` is called before you append your span and it returns an result set, as `#trash` didn't exist when you called the selector, so your event handler isn't bound to any element.

Use event delegation and attach the event handler to your `#tube` element instead:

```
$('#tube').on('click', '#trash', function(){
```