# One .click event handler for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating some buttons in my jQuery mobile website dynamically. I create them like this:

```
$('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').after('<button type="button" class="loadMorePhotos">More Photos...</button>');
```

Then I create a simple `.click` event handler like this :

```
$(".loadMorePhotos").click(function(){
            alert("ok malaka!");
});
```

I was cautious enough ***NOT*** to use the `id` attribute to identify the buttons , as I have multiple buttons and that would mess things up. Instead I use the `class` attribute that as far as I understand should work.

However the alert is never executed. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are binding the event handler *after* the element has been inserted? Please post a more complete example which shows the relation between those two statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: Thank you very much @Felix for your edit and for pointing out another very useful question. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".loadMorePhotos", function(){
        alert("ok malaka!");
});
```

Because your elements are dynamically created, you have to bind the click handler to an element that already exists at DOM ready (in this case, `document`)

Comment: Or bind the event handler to the element after it was created.