# JQuery not selecting added Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I found this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

, and when I'm trying to replicate the result and try the created `<a>` are not selected by jQuery

**My Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sonicdeadlock/y3ACz/

```
$(".addItem").on("click", function () {
    var newInput = $('<p><input type="text" class="item" placeholder="item"></input><a href="#" class="removeItem">remove</a></p>');
    $(this).closest(".category").append(newInput);
});

$(".removeItem").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("p").remove();
});
```

Comment: and [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: and [Turning live() into on() in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8021436/218196)

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding items, therefore you need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeItem", function() {
```

The reason being is that these handlers are bound at run, and at run, these new elements don't exist. Bind them to something that does. As for the working example you found, it uses `.live`. `.live` used to be used for this but was replaced with `.on` in later versions of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

`on()` has different syntax for delegation than the deprecated `live()` method does.

You first have to use a selector for an element, or the `document` itself that is a permanent asset of page, and is an ancestor of elements you want to target

Like:

```
$('.category').on('click', '.addItem',function(){
  /* handler code*/
})
```

OR

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeItem',function(){
  /* handler code*/
})
```

WHen elements are always in page you can use `on()` with the element as selector using the syntax you currently have.

**Thus there are two different ways to use `on()`**

[**API docs for on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Move your selector out to a parent that doesn't get replaced, and then filter down to the dynamic element(s):

```
$('body').on("click", ".addItem", function(){
    // your stuff here...
});
```

If you have something more specific than "body", I'd recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as live() is deprecated

Read  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeItem", function() { ..code here.. });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```