# Why Jquery script not execute after first time button click?

Tags: php, jquery

When i click next butoon of index.php, jquery performs its work, alert and loads the content of check.php in div 'result'.

But, Now when i again click on next button nothing happens, no alert, why ? I want that-alert should be displayed again and jquery should be load check.php as done on first click. Here is my code:

This is index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            $("button[name='next']").click(function() //when button clicked
            {
                var count= $('button[name=next]').val();      //value of button
                alert('button clicked');
                    $.ajax(
                    {url:"check.php",type: "POST",data: 'count='+ count,success:function(result)
                                                {
                                                        $("#result").html(result);
                                                }
                    });
            });             
    });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php   $_SESSION['count']='0'; ?>      
    <div id="result">
        <button name="next" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['count']);?>">Next</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is check.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['count']=$_POST['count']+1;
?>
<button name="next" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['count']);?>">Next</button>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: Also check http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/, and you really should use the latest jQuery version.

Comment: Try and id instead of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
     $("#result").on('click',"button[name='next']",function(){
        //.... your code goes here
     }
```

**Reason** : Click event you applied on the button is replaced by new button which does not have click event bind to it.

Solution :

1. Apply click event on new created [dynamically created] . see above code [**[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function in jquery]
2. Don't replace button,only replace your content.

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to update the `val()` of `$('button[name=next]')` , You could echo the value from php file and update it, instead of rewriting the button tag every time.

I would prefer doing this way

```
$.ajax({
    url:"check.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'count='+ count,
    success:function(result){
         $('button[name=next]').val(result);
        // $("#result").html(result);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php session_start();
       $_SESSION['count']=$_POST['count']+1;
       echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click',"button[name='next']",function()
```

this should work