# dynamic add and delete input field jquery 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm having trouble with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LetZh/23/) I found somewhere it works perfectly on 1.4 jquery
but I am using 1.10 version of Jquery.

I notice that `live` method is deprecated in 1.10 so I user `on` to replace `live` but still not doing as it supposed to do.

my toubled fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/L3s3w/)

I used to code back end so please spare me, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: Also have a look at how to **correctly** convert `.live` to `.on`: [Turning live() into on() in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8021436/218196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `parent selector` `$("#content")` with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) and use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to make `button` `disable` like,

```
$("#content").on("click", ".plus",function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest(".iteration");// use closest
    parent.append('<input type="text" value="Create a task for this iteration" />');
    var nbinput = parent.find("input[type='text']").length;
    if(nbinput == 5)
        parent.find(".plus").prop("disabled",true);// use prop()
    if(nbinput > 0)
        parent.find(".moins").prop("disabled",false);
});
$("#content").on("click",".moins", function(){       
    var parent = $(this).closest(".iteration");// use closest
    parent.children("input").last().remove();
    var nbinput = parent.find("input[type='text']").length;
    if(nbinput < 5)
        parent.find(".plus").prop("disabled",false);// use prop()
    if(nbinput == 0)
        parent.find(".moins").prop("disabled",true);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L3s3w/4/)

Answer (score 3):

To make `on` work like you wanted you need to specify an element that won't be changed as the main selector and pass the dynamic element selector as the second parameter:

```
$("#content").on("click", ".plus", function(){
```

Also, there was an error with the code that disabled the plus and minus buttons, instead of setting the disabled attribute to empty you want to remove it completely:

```
parent.find(".moins").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Finally, changed the `.parent().parent().parent('.iteration')` to

```
$(this).closest(".iteration");
```

As this is much simpler and less likely to be broken by changes to your html.

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/L3s3w/3/