# Javascript click function not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple script which make layer on background when popup div is shown.

```
jQuery(".openForm").click(function() {    
    jQuery("#popup").show();
    jQuery("body").append('<div id="layer"></div>');
});
```

This works fine but, when I click somewhere it should close popup with this script

```
jQuery("#layer").click(function() {    
    jQuery("#popup").hide();
    jQuery("#layer").remove();
});
```

anyway nothink happens, there is no error even.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Where are you binding the event?  Is it after the element exists?  Do you have multiple elements with the same ID (you can't do that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: and [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `#layer` doesn't exist when you attempt to bind the handler. Use event delegation instead:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', "#layer", function() {    
    jQuery("#popup").hide();
    jQuery("#layer").remove();
});
```

Alternatively, you could hide/show the `#layer` div (like the `#popup` div) instead of adding and removing it each time.

Comment: You'll probably want to remove the click handler from the document after the modal is closed.

Comment: @natewiley No, bind it once when the page loads, then leave it there.

Comment: i dont like messy html code so i remove things which are only for some reason with no specific content.