# click listener on a link element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically add the following element to the DOM.

`<li id="my-link"><a href="#">Click!</a></li>`

I need to keep `<a href="#">` part because of styling issues (Bootstrap), and I want to delete it upon clicking it. I change the above code with

`<li id="my-link"><a href="#" onclick='$(this).remove()'>Click!</a></li>`

It works fine. Then, I realize that I also append another `div` when I append the above element, so I need to remove both of the elements. I do the following

```
<li id="my-link"><a href="#">Click!</a></li>
$('#my-link').click(function (e) {
  $(e.target).remove();
  $('#my-div').remove();
});
```

However, nothing is triggered when the `click` event happens. I assume `href="#"` is causing this issue but can someone explain exactly why this is happening? As a workaround, I could just define a function `remove()`, and call it through `onclick='remove()'`, but I'd like to know why this is happening.

possible reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

**EDIT:**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var linkEl = '<li id="my-link"><a href="#">Click!</a></li>';
    var extraDiv = '<div id="my-div">Mydiv</div>';
    $('body').append(linkEl);
    $('body').append(extraDiv);
    $(linkEl).click(function (e) {
      console.log("this msg is not triggered when li is clicked. Why?");
      // delete both the link and extradiv
    });
  });
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gRaE/)

Comment: *"I do the following"* Is this exactly the HTML source you have? The code doesn't seem to be inside `<script>` tags and you are missing a `);` at the end.

Comment: Sorry. I just left it out in the question. You can assume syntax is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in your questions? Where's the div? What do you mean by "I realize that I also append another div when I append the above element"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: Thanks for the links! However, I don't think those two really address this specific problem. I edited the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your **linkEl**.  The variable is the string, not the DOM element.

When you run `$('body').append(linkEl);` jQuery converts the string into DOM elements, but you haven't updated your reference.

Try something like

```
var linkEl = '<a href="#">foo</a>';

// Reassign the variable to the DOM element created by jQuery.
linkEl = $('body').append(linkEl);

linkEl.click(function () {
  alert('hello');
});
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/9gRaE/3/) an updated example.

Comment: awesome :) This was the problem.