# jquery selector not finding elements when it loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

None of jQuery selectors working on loaded elements from server through Ajax requests, but it works good in normal mode.

```
$('#myid').change(function(){
  alert('OK!');
});

<select id="myid" >
 <option>1</option>
</select>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: it's not a bug, you just need to use the appropriate selector for your situation. For clicks for example, `on` or `live` or `delegate` will listen for clicks through AJAX loads where `click` will not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: I search About this And not find it. it's not duplicate question...your link just like my question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are loading content by ajax.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
$(document).on('change','#myid', function(){
   alert('OK!');
});
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myid').live('change', function(){
    //and scope from $(this) here
    $(this).parents().find('.class:first').attr('id');
});
```

it's looks good!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use live event

`$('#myid').live('change', function(){
   alert('OK!');
});`

Note : live event depericated in v1.9