# Reloading Select2 jQuery After AJAX Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-select2

I have a form that uses a Select2 multiple-selection field that is initialised like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#cred_form_1283_1_1_select-children').select2({
  dropdownParent: '#addChildModal',
  multiple: 'true',
  placeholder: 'Select Child(ren)'
  });
});
```

This works perfectly:

[image]

After an ajax submission or validation the Select2 doesn't load back into the form:

[image]

After reading numerous posts about this, I still cannot get it to work.  Example post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664216

I know you're supposed to reload it with an `on()` event handler, which I have tried in numerous ways, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#cred_form_1283_1_1').on('change','#cred_form_1283_1_1_select-children', function(){
    //alert('OK!');
    jQuery(this).select2({
      dropdownParent: '#addChildModal',
      multiple: 'true',
      placeholder: 'Select Child(ren)'
    });
  });
});
```

With the `#cred_form_1283_1_1` being the form ID, I have also tried this with **document** and neither work.

The `on()` is working as the commented alert box will trigger when the Select2 is updated, but the Select2 itself will not reload at all.

What is the error here?

Comment: What is your ajax doing to that select? are you realoading parts of the HTML? maybe the full selects gets reloaded?

Comment: @Diego Honestly, I don't know.  It's built through a suite of plugins called Toolset and all of that is handled behind the scenes.  I have nothing influencing it except this.  I have raised this with their support first and got told to go and look into this.  Please see the thread here:

https://toolset.com/forums/topic/reloading-select2-javascript-after-ajax-submission-validation/

Comment: Reading your question again, it is submitting the form and then resetting it without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue WAS related to the Toolset plugins.  I found a hook called **cred_form_ready** in their code that isn't documented, but if you use that then whenever the form is ready it works.

```
jQuery(document).on( 'cred_form_ready', function($) {
  jQuery('#cred_form_1283_1_1_select-children').select2({
    dropdownParent: '#addChildModal',
    multiple: 'true',
    placeholder: 'Select Child(ren)'
  });
});
```

This reloads the jQuery whenever any AJAX call is made and runs every time perfectly.