# Jquery append and remove li element attach issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mouse hover works at first, but when I click remove button and attach it is not working with mouse hover handler?? why?

thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<button id="a">remove</button><button id="b">attach</button>
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var k = 10; 
        myfunction(k);  
            $('#a').click(function(){   
                $('ul li').remove();    
            });         
            $('#b').click(function(){               
                k = 20;
                myfunction(k);          
            });     
            $('ul li').on('mouseenter',function () {
                var num = $(this).index();
                $('#lit' + num).addClass('currentpage');
                $('#lit' + num).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
                });

function myfunction(p){
    for(var i=0;i<p;i++){
        $('#container ul').append('<li id=lit'+i+'>Hello'+i+'</li>');
    }
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/JasonHu/8B9VH/5/

Comment: and [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829963/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward logic my friend:`li` elements to which you have attached `mouseenter` handler have been removed. Newly inserted `li` elements don't get `mouseenter` handler unless you attach them again after you insert them. In `myfunction` you have to attach `mouseenter` handlers for the newly inserted `li` elements. Change your code as shown below. Note the change - move the `mouseenter` handler attaching code inside `myfunction`.

```
var k = 10; 
myfunction(k);  
$('#a').click(function(){   
    $('ul li').remove();    
});         
$('#b').click(function(){               
    k = 20;
    myfunction(k);          
});

function myfunction(p){
    for(var i=0;i<p;i++){
        $('#container ul').append('<li id=lit'+i+'>Hello'+i+'</li>');
    }
    //Attach mouseenter handler after appending the li elements.
    $('ul li').on('mouseenter',function () {
        var num = $(this).index();
        $('#lit' + num).addClass('currentpage');
        $('#lit' + num).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so that the `mouseenter` event can be attached to the newly added list item:

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter','ul li', function() {

});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B9VH/7/)**

Comment: It might be helpful to explain why - when the selector `ul li` is executed for the mouseenter handler, it will only find the current `<li>`s inside the `<ul>`. By using the 2nd argument to `.on()` to specify a selector, you are using the fact that events propagate (bubble) up through the DOM to attach a handler to the `<ul>` that is never removed that will check if the original node that triggered the event matches the given selector, which is "li" in this case. This will work for all `<li>`s, regardless of when they were added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the function of binding the list and call it again after you generated a new list.

```
function BindMyList() {
        $('ul li').unbind('on');
        $('ul li').on('mouseenter', function () {
            var num = $(this).index();
            $('#lit' + num).addClass('currentpage');
            $('#lit' + num).siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
        });
    }
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B9VH/8/)