# Assign JavaScript to element from ajax query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a simple code like:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a href="#" class="plink">Click me</a>

<div class="cnt">

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".plink").click(function(){
     alert("A");
   });

$.ajax({
            url: 'do.php?a=getinfo',                        
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                $(".cnt").html(result);
            }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

From ajax query I get this:

```
<a href="#" class="plink">Click me 2</a>
```

The problem is that when I click on a link (Click me 2) that I get from ajax query, assigned for this link event doesn't work, i.e. `alert("A")` doesn't show.
So, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: and [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829963/218196)

Comment: Since the answers fail to get the point across (IMO): Have a look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.click()is not bindable with dynamic elements.
Try this,

```
$("body").on("click",".plink",function(e){
     alert("A");
});
```

else

```
$(".plink").live(function(e){
         alert("A");
});
```

Comment: .live() is deprecated in newest versions of jQuery. See the docs https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Evgeny: Make sure you understand *why*. Have a look at this more elaborated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12830031/218196 and follow the links.

Answer (score 0):

New element from your ajax result has no binded click action. Try to use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.plink', function(){ alert("A"); });
```

instead of:

```
$(".plink").click(function(){ alert("A"); });
```

Comment: Why should the OP try that? Please **explain** your solution.

Comment: I edited my answer with explanation above a few minutes ago. Sorry