# jQuery successfully binds events on elements that aren't in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I was investigating a bug and decided to review the `jQuery.on()` docs to make sure I understood delegated events. [I was surprised to read](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

I was surprised because I'd been binding events to elements **not** in the DOM, and upon inserting the elements into the DOM, those elements would respond to events that bubbled through!

I was so confused by this statement that even tested my understand of it. You can find this test here: http://jsfiddle.net/eUuv4/.

In summary, I make a Backbone View:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<div class="inner"><button>Say hello</button></div>'),
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.name = options.name;
        this.$el.append($(this.template()));
    },
    events: {
        'click button': function () { 
            console.log('Hello from ' + this.name);
        }
    },
});
```

And then construct it with two different elements: one that is in the DOM; and one that is not in the DOM when the view is constructed. Upon inserting the second variant into the DOM, as I expected, its element responds to delegated events that pass through it.

So, what are the jQuery docs trying to say with the above quoted statement?

Comment: I think it's just poorly worded. It simply means that the element must *exist*. But it doesn't have to be part of the document.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok, that's what I thought for a secnd, but what's the point of saying that, or even bolding that. How/why would you try to bind an event on a non-existing element? Does this mean people do `$('.i-know-this-doesnt-exist').on('click', function() {});` and expect it to magically bind when the element does exist??

Comment: I think the sequence of events is not happening the way you think it is. I don't know Backbone, but for the .on() method, only the _selector_ to which the listener is bound must exist. The delegated elements under it do not need to exist when the listener is instantiated.

Comment: @dimadima: Yes. People are selecting the elements of a specific class and wonder why elements with that class, which are created *later* on, don't have that event handler.

Comment: You are massively confusing backbone and jQuery. Here is a demo showing that .on() only binds to elements that exist at the time of execution: http://jsfiddle.net/Kk3ny/. And the reason you may want to bind elements that don't exist is because they might be created/loaded in the future.

Comment: @FelixKling: that's crazy. Oh well! Hah! :D

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829963/218196

Comment: I think backbone is using event delegation to handle the events... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tCP23/1/ - because an element which was created after the rendering of the main view also is firing the event

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers."

Comment: Yes, my example/fiddle unfortunately requires knowing that Backbone uses `$.fn.on()` and delegates. Anyway, thanks for clarifying, @FelixKling

Comment: I might be wrong, but what backbone does seems to be irrelevant here. The op could also have asked why does `$('<div />').on('click', ...)` works even thought the element is not "in the DOM". That's why I avoid the phrase "in the DOM" and use "document" instead.

Comment: Yes, when I read "they must exist on the page" I interpret this to mean `element.parentNode` is not null or a document fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just poorly worded. It simply means that the element must *exist* at the moment the handler is bound.

Whether the element is part of the document or whether you created it programmatically  (and haven't added it to the document yet) doesn't matter.

---

> How/why would you try to bind an event on a non-existing element?

I think it's partly jQuery's fault, because it made things so easy / provided such a high level abstraction. People starting with jQuery often don't have any idea how event handling in JavaScript actually works.

The existence of the (now deprecated) `.live` method also contributed to this misconception. I mean, if you see

```
$('.foo').live('click', ...);
```

then it's only a small step to believe that jQuery always, *magically*, handles every element with that class, whether it exists now or in the future.

Introducing `.on` was a step in the right direction to "demystify" jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Pretty poor wording for something bolded and so integral. Really made me re-evaluate my career choices for a minute.