# jQuery Manipulating Temporary Elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list with the id #list with no list items in it. In my jQuery script, I have a function that sets the HTML inside of #list to some list items.

```
$('#list').click(function() {
    $('#list').html("<li> blah </li> <li> blooh </li>");
});
```

But afterwards, when I try to manipulate $('#list li'):

```
$('#list li').mouseenter(function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: and [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working because the click handler is only being applied to things that are in the DOM.
Try this:

```
$('#list').delegate('li','click',function(){
   this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Delegate will bind elements that do not yet exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery v1.7+, use `.on()` in its delegated form like :

```
$('#list').click(function () {
    $('#list').html("<li> blah </li> <li> blooh </li>");
}).on("mouseenter", "li", function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}).on("mouseleave", "li", function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uhCyX/)**

**Notice** that you can chain the events

Comment: I didn't know that `on` has a "delegated form". Is there any difference internally between that and `delegate`?

Comment: @Mike: `delegate` is obsolete and calls `on` internally. See https://api.jquery.com/delegate/.