# Extremely basic jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been using jQuery for a while now but this problem has never happened before.

Basically, HTML:

```
<div class="button three"></div>
<div id="Content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.button.three {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: blue;
 }

.textBlock {
    background: orange;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".button.three").click(function() {
        $("<div class='textBlock'></div>").appendTo("#Content");
    });

    $(".textBlock").click(function() {
        alert("2");
    });

});
```

See the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Brannie19/cQk8t/

Why doesn't this work?

---EDIT---
I was wondering why the click event on `.textBlock` wouldnt fire. The answers from dsaa and net.uk.sweet actually explained it to me, so thank you guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: and [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQk8t/1/)

You're assigning an event to an element that doesn't exist in the DOM.

Instead, search the document for the element and action a function on finding.

    `$(".button.three").click(function() {
        $('#Content').append('<div class="textBlock"></div>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.textBlock', function(){alert("2");});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to add a listener to an element which doesn't exist yet. The solution is to delegate the event to the parent element which does exist using the jQuery on method (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".button.three").click(function() {
            $("<div class='textBlock'></div>").appendTo("#Content");
        });

        $("#Content").on('click', '.textBlock', function() {
            alert("2");
        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YNWX8/

Comment: I thought that was the problem because if I added the click event to the $("<div class='textBlock'></div>"), it would work. Thank you very much :) I couldnt figure out how to work it.

I would upvote your answer but I cant yet because I dont have enough rep yet :(

Comment: No worries. I upvoted you so hopefully you're on your way ;)