# jQuery Global Event Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

ttI have two functions like so:

```
function fn1() {
    $(".element").append("<div class='trigger'></div>");
}

function fn2() {
    $(".element").append("<div class='trigger'></div>");
}
```

and one listener:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    // do some magic with $(this) element
});
```

The problem is that if click event listener is located outside fn1 and fn2 it doesn't see when dynamically created element (trigger) is clicked.

How can I make event listener to listen globally?

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829963/218196

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/qPYLh/)***

Delegate the click handler to all current and future instances of `.trigger` using **[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$("body").on("click",".trigger",function() {
    // do some magic with $(this) element
});
```

---

*edit*

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ppF4k/)***

> Re: Could you also advise how to create hover listener with on statement please?

Hover is indeed a corner case here. With the fluent approach you could use `$().hover(function(){},function(){})`. However, this is not the case with using `on`. In order to use it with on you actually have to use two separate delegations with **[`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)** and **[`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**

```
$("body").on("mouseenter",".trigger",function() {
    // do some magic with $(this) element
});
$("body").on("mouseleave",".trigger",function() {
    // do some magic with $(this) element
});
```

Comment: this didn't work, still doesn't see the click event. The problem only persists because new element is created inside function. If I put listener inside function too then it can see the click event

Comment: @user3695709 - There must be something else affecting your code. Do you see any errors in your console? Look at this jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qPYLh/ It demonstrates this approach working.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Could you also advise how to create hover listener with on statement please?

Comment: @user3695709 - Sure, see edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".trigger", function() {
// do some magic with $(this) element
});
```

Comment: What does this do? Why does it solve the OP's problem? Please **explain** your solution (and the problem).

Comment: Because the trigger class is added to the dom after loading. It is therefore re-check the DOM in some way, so find the famous class and trigger the corresponding event when clicked.

Comment: This doesn't recheck the DOM, the event is bound to `body` and when `body` hears the click it delegates the event to `.trigger`, so if `.trigger` is the target or an ancestor of the target, the event will be executed.