# jQuery - Can not select a dynamic created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<table id="items" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Location</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="addName"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="addDescription"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
function getTable(){
    var args = new Object();
    args.op = "getTable";
    $.post("./service.php", args , function(data)
        {
            var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i = 0; i<dataObj.length; i++){
                $('table#items tbody').append("<tr class=\"items_tr\" id=\"item"+dataObj[i].sn+"\"><td>"+dataObj[i].sn+"</td><td>"+dataObj[i].name+"</td><td>"+dataObj[i].description+"</td><td>"+dataObj[i].belonged+"</td></tr>");
        }
    });
}

getTable();

$('tbody').children("tr").hide();
$("tbody tr").hide();
$("tr.items_tr").hide();
```

The Last 3 statements do not work at all.
Cannot select created <tr>s.
Why and how can I select them?

```
$("tr").hide();
```

This one hides only  <tr>s inside  <thead>, things that have already been created.

**more questions** - How about .each() function?
I want to bind a click event on each td tag, and I failed again..
How to iterate all new added <td>s?

Comment: Its an async call... need to wait for it to finish before making selections.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last three statements to work, the elements have to **exist**. You are executing those methods **before** the Ajax response was received. Move the calls inside the `$.get` callback, after you added the elements (i.e. after the loop).

Kind of related (because they explain how async stuff works):

- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: So there is no way to select it except inside the ajax calls?

Comment: @JeanYang: You can't select what doesn't exist. You could hide an existing *ancestor* of the rows though, which would have a similar effect.

Comment: I don't really want to hide it, and I want to do something else on it, like binding a .on() function. I just want to make sure that I can select it.

Comment: If you want to bind event handlers, you can use event delegation instead, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand

Comment: So I have to write an ancestor (container) for it, and do something on its ancestor?

Comment: If you are talking about event delegation, you can use any existing ancestor. E.g. `$('#items').on('click', 'tr', function() { ... });`.

Comment: OK, and how about selecting its descendants(e.g. td tags)?

Comment: If you want to target `td`s only, just change the selector to `td`. If you want to select them when the event occurs, inside the event handler `this` refers to the `tr` element and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Sorry, I have more questions - how about .each() function? I want to bind a click event on each td tag, and I failed again..

Comment: Again, use event delegation. `$('#items').on('click', 'td', function() { ... });` will capture every click on every `td` element. Or bind the handler inside the Ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide these elements on an event, add them to an event handler for example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        getTable();

        $(element).on('click', function () {
            $('tbody').children("tr").hide();
            $("tbody tr").hide();
            $("tr.items_tr").hide();
        });
     )};
```

If you are trying to hide these elements right after call the getTable function then add the 3 functions to the $.post success function

code should look like:

```
function getTable(){
var args = new Object();
args.op = "getTable";
$.post("./service.php", args , function(data)
    {
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i = 0; i<dataObj.length; i++){
            $('table#items tbody').append("<tr class=\"items_tr\" id=\"item"+dataObj[i].sn+"\"><td>"+dataObj[i].sn+"</td><td>"+dataObj[i].name+"</td><td>"+dataObj[i].description+"</td><td>"+dataObj[i].belonged+"</td></tr>");
    }
        $('tbody').children("tr").hide();
        $("tbody tr").hide();
        $("tr.items_tr").hide();
});
}

 getTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi jquery binds events on document.ready if there are elements which are created after document.ready then you need to register those elements for those events using .bind() function of jquery. But be sure first unregister alredy attached elements. using unbind();

Refer bind and unbind functions.