# Javascript, Jquery ,DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

After appending a button on Html document the jQuery event associated with it not working ?

For example:

```
$("#mydiv").append('<a href="#" id="mybutton">X</a>');//this is button appending

$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: you gotta wait a ms or 2, or use $("#mydiv").on("click","#mybutton", ... )

Comment: Is this your actual code (i.e. do these lines run sequentially)? In that case, do you have more than one element matching `#mybutton` in your document?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xwrpf5gq/...

Comment: It works. If it doesn't, it's probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829963/218196

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you call the `.click()` method on `#mybutton` before it is actually appended to `#mydiv`, you need to use [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the button doesn't exist when you attach the event handler:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click','#mybutton',function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Should work...

Comment: If the code is as he posted, he adds the element before attaching the handler, so he doesn't need to do this.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, I assumed that wasn't the case, as otherwise the original code would work...

Comment: Either way, if that's the reason then the question should be closed as duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829963/218196. We really don't need more of these.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the `click` *inside* the `append`?

This way you wouldn't need to concern about the element being added or not to the document's flow, since you'd be setting the event callback on the actual DOM element variable:

```
$("#mydiv").append(
    $('<a href="#" id="mybutton">X</a>').click(function() {
        alert("hello");
    })
);
```