# Jquery events do not work on dynamically appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append new DOM objects to some Div and it works, but somehow - the events that I programmed for these new appended objects do not respond. Why is that?

I attach here a simple example: upon click on any paragraph the paragraph should hide. Yet, for paragraph that were added using .append, it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/xV3HN/

There's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").click(function(){
     $("#containerDiv").append("<p> I should hide as well if you click me </p>");
  });

 $("p").click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: Take a look at Event Delegation https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: and [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/218196)

Comment: This is probably one of the top 10 most asked JavaScript questions.

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1359018/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11294997/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16462052/218196

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use `.on` to handle events of dynamic elements.
 
 try this:

```
  $(document).on('click', 'p', function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xV3HN/1/)

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#add").click(function(){
     $("#containerDiv").append("<p> I should hide as well if you click me </p>");
  });

 $("body").on("click","p", function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: This helped me and is more good when working with dynamically created elements.