# Making a tooltip for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a tooltip that works for dynamically created elements. Right now, the tooltip that I make only works for elements processed when the page loads. Here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/ttkz4krg/

I tried to follow the link below to get my function to work on dynamically created elements:

[Jquery events do not work on dynamically appended elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131961/jquery-events-do-not-work-on-dynamically-appended-elements)

And so I tried doing this with the

```
$(document).on('event', 'element', function () {
});
```

method. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/thwtLh7p/

But I can't manage to get it to work. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start from `body` tag not `document` element

```
$('body').on('event', 'element', function () {

});
```