# Working with Jquery appended elements in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom

I am trying to make an invoicing application. Now, where I make users add new rows to invoice, I am providing a dropdownlist where they can select a product and then using jquery getting all the other information like price, discount etc from database. This is working fine.
Now keeping rest of the information as it is, I have to provide ADD button to add more rows of products and finally insert all of the info to db.
I have been partially able to do it using jquery in multiple ways such as 'clone' or 'append' methods. It results in creating new rows perfectly. I change the IDs of the elements successfully too.
Now, since the generated output is DOM and not actual HTML markup, I cannot get around to actually use the newly generated controls IDs or values to make further changes. Also how will I get the values of all the new rows and pass it to controller for insertion to database. I am really confused. 
I know it's lack of complete understanding of the concepts but if anyone can shed some light, it will be great. Thanks.

`

> Jquery method I am using to append a partial view

```
function AddRows(e) {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: '/CreateInvoices/Creator',
                data: { incr: e },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#datarow").append(data);
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
        }
```

> Handling 'products' change function

```
 $('.Prods').change(function () {
                $.get("/CreateInvoices/GetProductInfo",
                    { ProductId: $("#prodid").val() },
                    function (data) {
                        $("#price").empty();
                        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                            $("#price").val(row.PricePerUnit);
                            discid = row.DiscountId;
                        });

                        alert($('#price')[0].id);

                        $.get("/CreateInvoices/GetDiscountInfo",
                            { DiscountId: discid },
                            function (data) {
                                $("#disc").empty();
                                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                                    $("#disc").val(row.DiscountNo);

                                });
                            });

                    });
            });
            });
```

> Calling partial view

```
 <table id="datarow">
        @Html.Partial("_Inv")
    </table>
```

> My partial view

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("ProductId", null, "-- Select Product --", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "prodid" + @ViewBag.y, @class = "Prods" })
    </td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Price", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "price" + @ViewBag.y, @class = "my-form-control" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Qty", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "qty" + @ViewBag.y, @class = "my-form-control" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Discount", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "disc" + @ViewBag.y, @class = "my-form-control" })</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="my-form-control" /></td>
    <td>
        <input id="btnAdd" type="button" onclick="AddRows(@ViewBag.y)" value="+" />
        @if (ViewBag.y is null || ViewBag.y <= 0)
        {
//
        }
        else
        {
            <input id="btnRem1" type="button" value="-" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)" />
        }
    </td>
</tr>`
```

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for a detailed implementation using `BeginCollectionItem`

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the path. I have got to the point where now the new rows are added with a hidden field and unique names for each control. Now how do I work with these controls, I still cannot figure out. Like new drop down are being added, when they change how do I catch the change event in jquery. I can only catch change event of the first row. For the rest even if I change the code to get change events on specific IDs  which I am sure are being created, nothing happens.

Comment: Found the piece to the puzzle.. Works perfectly now![Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22131985/10395600)